# Plant identification?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Can anyone identify the plant below? It's in a backyard in Pennsylvania, and the photo was taken today.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided more photos, such as a detail of the flower (where petals and other structural elements can be counted), the stem, the leaves, etc.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about plant identification. These questions are usually asked on Gardening and Landscaping Stack Exchange. This topic is not found in the following appropriate topics listing in the Help center: 1) General questions about biological concepts 2) Questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions 3) Questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Comment: Gardening and Landscaping only? what about the wild plants?

Comment: And when asker don't know whether it is cultivated or wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those flowers don't come from the same plant as that big leaf in the front do they?  Cant help you with the leaves, but the flower looks like a [daylily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylily). source: I know nothing about plants, but happen to have a mom who got a degree in horticulture :)
[image: Sweet daylily picture from wikipedia]

Comment: And the big leaf could come from some kind of zucchini. Source: grandmas garden.

Answer (score 1):

The flower is a *Hemerocallis fulva* (Hemerocallidaceae).

The leaf seems to be a Cucurbitaceae, as said above, the same family as the zucchini